# XML Query not returning expected results

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Accommodations>
 <AccommodationSegment AccommodationCode="627|26234" AccommodationId="15390132" AccommodationName="blah" Availability="available" BasicAdultCost="180.16" BoardCode="SC" BookableByFAB="true" BrandName="blah" ClassCode="2*" Currency="GBP" EndDate="20170918" ItineraryId="si1068" MaxChildAge="17" NormalisedName="BLAH" NumNights="7" ResortId="558" ResortName="blah" StartDate="20170911" Supplier="TT2" SyndicatorRanking="100" Type="Apartments">
  <AvailableBoardBasis>BB</AvailableBoardBasis>
  <AvailableBoardBasis>HB</AvailableBoardBasis>
  <AvailableBoardBasis>SC</AvailableBoardBasis>
  <Address Address1="blah" Address2="blah" Address3="Tenerife" CityOrTown="Puerto de la Cruz" Country="ES" PostCode="34324" />
  <TelephoneNumber>+34 922370565</TelephoneNumber>
  <Description>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</Description>
  <GeoPosition Latitude="28.4129" Longitude="-16.5437" />
  <DirectLink System="FABRIX">
     <DirectLinkURL><![CDATA[https://ww9.website.com/deep_linking/deep_linking.html?rooms=1&amp;journey=Hotels&amp;checkinDate=11092017&amp;duration=7&amp;suppliers=TT2&amp;accommodationId=15390132]]></DirectLinkURL>
  </DirectLink>
  <AccommodationUnits>
     <AccommodationUnit AUID="H2" Code="2SC" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" MaxOccupancy="1" MinOccupancy="1" Name="Studio - Self catering" QuantityAvailable="9">
        <RoomRate Amount="180.16" BoardBasis="SC" Currency="GBP" EndDate="20170918" RefundType="refundable" StartDate="20170911" />
     </AccommodationUnit>
     <AccommodationUnit AUID="H2" Code="2BB" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" MaxOccupancy="1" MinOccupancy="1" Name="Studio - Bed and Breakfast" QuantityAvailable="9">
        <RoomRate Amount="216.91" BoardBasis="BB" Currency="GBP" EndDate="20170918" RefundType="refundable" StartDate="20170911" />
     </AccommodationUnit>
     <AccommodationUnit AUID="H2" Code="2HB" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" MaxOccupancy="1" MinOccupancy="1" Name="Studio - Half board" QuantityAvailable="9">
        <RoomRate Amount="268.36" BoardBasis="HB" Currency="GBP" EndDate="20170918" RefundType="refundable" StartDate="20170911" />
     </AccommodationUnit>
  </AccommodationUnits>
  </AccommodationSegment>
 <AccommodationSegment AccommodationCode="627|26234"  AccommodationId="15390132" AccommodationName="blah" Availability="available" BasicAdultCost="180.16" BoardCode="SC" BookableByFAB="true" BrandName="blah" ClassCode="2*" Currency="GBP" EndDate="20170918" ItineraryId="si1068" MaxChildAge="17" NormalisedName="BLAH" NumNights="7" ResortId="558" ResortName="blah" StartDate="20170911" Supplier="TT2" SyndicatorRanking="100" Type="Apartments">
  <AvailableBoardBasis>BB</AvailableBoardBasis>
  <AvailableBoardBasis>HB</AvailableBoardBasis>
  <AvailableBoardBasis>SC</AvailableBoardBasis>
  <Address Address1="blah" Address2="blah" Address3="Tenerife" CityOrTown="Puerto de la Cruz" Country="ES" PostCode="73737" />
  <TelephoneNumber>0034 922384811</TelephoneNumber>
  <Description>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
  blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</Description>
  <GeoPosition Latitude="28.4119" Longitude="-16.5473" />
  <DirectLink System="FABRIX">
     <DirectLinkURL><![CDATA[https://ww9.website.com/deep_linking/deep_linking.html?rooms=1&amp;journey=Hotels&amp;checkinDate=12092017&amp;duration=7&amp;suppliers=TT2&amp;accommodationId=16271549]]></DirectLinkURL>
  </DirectLink>
  <AccommodationUnits>
     <AccommodationUnit AUID="H4476" Code="4476BB" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" MaxOccupancy="1" MinOccupancy="1" Name="Double Room for Single Use - Bed and Breakfast" QuantityAvailable="9">
        <RoomRate Amount="250.04" BoardBasis="BB" Currency="GBP" EndDate="20170919" RefundType="non_refundable" StartDate="20170912" />
     </AccommodationUnit>
     <AccommodationUnit AUID="H4476" Code="4476HB" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" MaxOccupancy="1" MinOccupancy="1" Name="Double Room for Single Use - Half board" QuantityAvailable="9">
        <RoomRate Amount="276.97" BoardBasis="HB" Currency="GBP" EndDate="20170919" RefundType="non_refundable" StartDate="20170912" />
     </AccommodationUnit>
     <AccommodationUnit AUID="H4476" Code="4476FB" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" MaxOccupancy="1" MinOccupancy="1" Name="Double Room for Single Use - Full board" QuantityAvailable="9">
        <RoomRate Amount="303.88" BoardBasis="FB" Currency="GBP" EndDate="20170919" RefundType="non_refundable" StartDate="20170912" />
     </AccommodationUnit>
     <AccommodationUnit AUID="H4476" Code="4476AI" MaxExtraChildren="0" MaxExtraInfants="0" MaxOccupancy="1" MinOccupancy="1" Name="Double Room for Single Use - All inclusive" QuantityAvailable="9">
        <RoomRate Amount="317.34" BoardBasis="AI" Currency="GBP" EndDate="20170919" RefundType="non_refundable" StartDate="20170912" />
     </AccommodationUnit>
  </AccommodationUnits>
  </AccommodationSegment>
</Accommodations>
```

And the following xpath query:-

```
(//*[local-name()="AccommodationSegment" and //*["RoomRate"][@RefundType="non_refundable"]])[1]
```

Why does the query return the first  (Hotel) that contains 'refundable' rooms and not the second hotel which contains 'non_refundable' hotels?  What is wrong with the query and/or is there a query which will work?

Comment: What exact output you want to get?

Comment: I want the first <AccommodationSegment> that contains non-refundable rooms which, in the xml, is an attribute 'RefundType' of <RoomRate>. Using this tool:http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester  you will find my query returns the first <AccommodationSegment> which contains 'refundable' and not what I would expect - the first <AccommodationSegment> which contains non_refundable

Comment: Are you sure you need `AccommodationSegment`, but not `AccommodationUnits` or `AccommodationUnit`? There is only one `AccommodationSegment` on provided `xml` sample and it has both `<RoomRate RefundType="non_refundable">` and `<RoomRate RefundType="refundable">`

Comment: sorry, I pasted the wrong xml - now updated. Yes, I need the     `AccommodationSegment` which has `non_refundable` rooms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below `XPath` expression to match first `AccommodationSegment` element that contains `<RoomRate RefundType="non_refundable">`:

```
(//AccommodationSegment[./descendant::RoomRate[@RefundType="non_refundable"]])[1]
```

or you can modify your `XPath` as

```
(//*[local-name()="AccommodationSegment" and .//*[@RefundType="non_refundable"]])[1]
```

Note that

1. I removed `["RoomRate"]` predicate as string will always return `True`
2. I replaced `//*[@RefundType...` with `.//*[@RefundType...` as your expression means

> find any element if its name is `"AccommodationSegment"` and if there is any element with attribute `RefundType="non_refundable"` **SOMEWHERE** in the document

while my expression means:

> find any element if its name is `"AccommodationSegment"` and if **IT CONTAINS** any element with attribute `RefundType="non_refundable"`